# Why is this lexer not parsing this input?

Tags: haskell, alex

I want to lex the following code example:

```
prop levelBasedAlerter uni { a b } \I -> 
  levelBasedAlerter a                           
    | a > I ->                                   
      b: "ALERT: %a"
```

this should be

```
Prop
Var "levelBasedAlerter"
Uni
PortSpecS " { a b }"
Lam
Var "I"
PatternMatchEnd
Indent 2
Var "levelBasedAlerter"
Var "a"
Indent 4
PatternGuard
Var "a"
Var ">"
Var "I" 
PatternMatchEnd
Indent 6
Var "b"
DefinedByCol
StringLit "Alert: %a"
```

however, my alex lexer stops with an error on encountering `\` in the first line (with and without a space behind the `\`).

Why is this the case?
The Lexer:

```
{
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
module Lexer where
import Data.Typeable
import Data.Data
import Data.List
import Data.List.Split
import Data.Char
import Debug.Trace
import Prelude hiding (lex)
import Control.Monad (liftM)
}

%wrapper "posn"

$digit            = 0-9
@string           = (. # [\" \\] )

$alpha            = [a-zA-Z]
@real             = ($digit+ \. | $digit * \. $digit +)
@boolLit          = ("True"|"False")
@alphaNum         = ($alpha|$digit)+
$bracketsOpen     = [\(\[\{]
$bracketsClose    = [\)\]\}]
$brackets         = [ $bracketsOpen $bracketsClose]
@identifier       = [^ : ! = \\ \ " $brackets]+
@commaOrSpace     = (\,\ * | \ +)
@scopedIdentifier = @identifier(\.@identifier)+
@globalKeyword    = (prop|mesh|let|omni|uni|let|using|module|import|where)
@port             = (@identifier:\ *)?@identifier
@portSpec         = ((@identifier|@scopedIdentifier):)?
                    " "*
                        \{\ * @port
                            (@commaOrSpace @port)*
                        " "*\} 
@deepPortSpec     = ((@identifier|@scopedIdentifier):)?
                    " "*
                        \{\ * @identifier: (. # \})+ \} 
@indent           = \n[\t\ ]+

tokens :-
    @indent         { \_ s -> Indent $ length s }
    $white+         ;
    "--".*          ;
    @globalKeyword  { \_ keyword -> getTokenOf keyword }
    $digit+         { \_ s -> IntL (read s) }
    @real+          { \_ s -> DoubleL (read s) }
    @boolLit        { \_ s -> BoolL (read s) }
    \" @string \"   { \_ s -> StringLit (tail . init $ s) }
    @portSpec       { \_ s -> PortSpecS s } 
    @deepPortSpec   { \_ s -> DeepPortSpecS s }
    ":"             { \_ s -> DefinedByCol }
    ","             { \_ s -> Comma }
    "!"             { \_ s -> Negate }
    "=="            { \_ s -> Eq }
    "="             { \_ s -> LetAssOp }
    "~>"            { \_ s -> Wire }
    "->"            { \_ s -> PatternMatchEnd }
    $bracketsOpen   { \_ s -> BracO s}
    $bracketsClose  { \_ s -> BracC s}
    "||"            { \_ s -> Or }
    "|"             { \_ s -> PatternGuard}
    "!!"            { \_ s -> AccessPort }
    "\\"            { \_ s -> Lam }

    @scopedIdentifier {\_ s -> ScopedVar s }
    @identifier     { \_ s -> Var s }

{

clean :: String -> String
clean s = reverse $ rmWs $ reverse $ rmWs s
    where rmWs = dropWhile (\c -> c ==' ' || c == '\t')

traceThis :: (Show a) => a -> a
traceThis a = trace ("DEBUG: " ++ show a) a

data Token
           = Prop
           | Mesh
           | Module
           | Import
           | Where
           | Var String
           | BracO String
           | BracC String
           | Comma
           | Eq
           | PatternGuard
           | Or
           | ScopedVar String 
           | Omni
           | Uni
           | PortSpecS String
           | DeepPortSpecS String
           | DefinedByCol                       -- ':' after definitions
           | Indent Int
           | PatternMatchEnd                    -- '->' after PM
           | Negate    
           | Let 
           | LetAssOp                           -- '=' in let x = ...
           | Wire
           | AccessPort
           | Using
           | Lam
           | StringLit String
           | IntL Int
           | DoubleL Double
           | BoolL Bool
           | EOF 
    deriving (Eq,Show,Data)

getTokenOf :: String -> Token
getTokenOf s = fromConstr 
             $ head $ filter ((==s) . map toLower . showConstr) 
             $ dataTypeConstrs $ dataTypeOf $ Prop



}
```

I think it has something to do with how i match for the `\` token.
However, I have tried matching it like

`'\'` `'\\'` `"\"` `"\\"` `\\` `\` and also with a regular expression, but nothing seems to work.

Is there some weird behavior regarding `\` in alex? or is it some other trivial error that I am unable to see?

**Update**

I tried changing the `@identifier` to this now:

```
@identifier       = (. # [ : ! = \\ \ " $brackets])+
```

to do "anything except for x" matching in an alexy way but this did not change anything in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to read your lex rules, unfortunately. But you have two mistakes in your token definitions.

First, the following:

```
 "\\"   {\_ s -> Lam}
```

should be:

```
  "\"   {\_ s -> Lam}
```

(Note that we do *not* escape the back-slash.) This is counter-intuitive indeed, but this is the syntax of an Alex rule, and thus you shouldn't to quote the back-slash there. (Otherwise, it'll match two backslashes, back-to-back.)

The second is that your rule:

```
    \" @string \"  { \_ s -> StringLit (tail . init $ s) }
```

should be:

```
    \" @string* \"  { \_ s -> StringLit (tail . init $ s) }
```

(Note the star after `@string`.) That is, your strings need to accept 0 or more characters in them.

If you make the above two changes, you'll see that your input now goes through without problems.

However, it appears that you're trying to do too much in your lexer: A lexer should really be very simple; and it should definitely not contain complicated rules like `portSpec` that you have. Instead, you should simply tokenize into basic constituents (more or less delimited by white-space except for strings), and then you should use a proper parser generator like Happy to do the actual parsing of your language. This is the standard methodology.

Comment: but shouldn't the `[^` in the identifier rule specify that any character may be part of an identifier EXCEPT for the characters and classes inside the `[^ .. ]` ;
I know that's at least the regex syntax for this semantics

Comment: about how much stuff the lexer contais: I am aware of that, and I have started to change that slowly; if I knew for sure that the problem was not linked to these parts I wouldn't have posted them; I mainly wanted to understand why it fails in this case

Comment: You're quite right; I misread your definitions at first. I updated my answer to reflect the actual problems. But the final message remains the same; make your lexer much simpler, and use Happy to do the actual parsing.

Comment: it is interesting that no escape is needed, and this was the only combination I haven't tried; thanks very much; i am actually simplifying it right now; got the wrong impression from some code samples on how much should be in there.